# sympy expression to symbols

Tags: python, sympy

I want to take an expression and split it by symbols. For example

```
rate = symbols('0')  
def add_rate(self, new_rate):  
    self.rate = self.rate + symbols(new_rate)

add_rate('-k\*A\*E')
```

So the whole thing is `0 + -k\*A\*E`. After that I want to change `k` to `0.01` with method `subs(symbol('k'), 0.01)` to be `0 + -0.01\*A\*E` and I can't cause whole expression `-k\*A\*E` is the symbol.

Maybe do you know how to change `k` to `0.01`?

Comment: Found a solution. parse_expr

Comment: If you solved the problem, write and answer and submit it so that others who find this page can benefit. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer I can't answet my own question yet, so I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solusion is using the sympy.parsing.sympy_parser opportunities.

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import *
rate = symbols('0')
def add_rate(self, new_rate):
self.rate = self.rate + parse_expr(new_rate.rate_string)
```